# Embedded lightning-icon onclick event not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, event

I'm trying to embed an `lightning-icon` in an `lightning-input` field to hide/display the password value.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-3">Password</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
     <lightning-input required type="password" value={password} onchange={handlePasswordChange} maxlength="64" minlength="8" style="font-weight:bold;"></lightning-input>
     <lightning-icon onclick={togglePw} size="x-small" class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:hide"></lightning-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Example from: https://www.forcetrails.com/2020/05/how-to-create-lightning-input-with-icon-lwc.html)

In this combination, the onclick event dont fire my `togglePw` function. (no erros in the js-console)

When I deploy the `lightning-icon` separately, the event works.

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-3">Password</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
     <lightning-input required type="password" value={password} onchange={handlePasswordChange} maxlength="64" minlength="8" style="font-weight:bold;"></lightning-input>
  </div>
</div>

<lightning-icon onclick={togglePw} size="x-small" class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:hide"></lightning-icon>
```

Why does the event work if it is not embedded

togglePw function:

```
togglePw() {
    console.log('togglePw');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is
Salesforce standard style has

```
.slds-input-has-icon .slds-input__icon:not(button) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Adding pointer-events back, it will work..

```
<lightning-icon onclick={togglePw} size="x-small"  class="iconenablepointerevetns slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right slds-icon-text-default" icon-name="utility:hide"></lightning-icon>
```

with css

```
.slds-input__icon.iconpointerevetns{
    pointer-events:all
}
```

Comment: perfect! this solved my issue!!

Comment: This approach may introduce accessibility issues. A lightning-button-icon would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

For accessibility purposes, you should use [lightning-button-icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-icon) if you need a clickable icon. You should not generally mess with the standard SLDS styles unless you've researched the ramifications of doing so.